# how to add array values inputted in one edittext in java eclipse?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am making a program that add the array values. My input is like this way...
for example i will input:
10-20,20-30,30-40
It will loop and the computation goes this way..
(10+20)+(20+30)+(30+40)

I have a hard time thinking how am i going to do this..Please help me..Thank you.

here's my code:

```
   final AutoCompleteTextView interval_Values = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.interval_Values);
   final TextView txtArithmetc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtArithmetic);

    Button btncalculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncalculate);
    btncalculate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
            String[]x_value = interval_Values.getText().toString().split("-");
            double[]value = new double[x_value.length];
            String[]weight_value =interval_Values.getText().toString().split(",");
            double[]value1 = new double[weight_value.length];

              double sum = 0;
              double sum1=0;
              double result=0;

              for(int i = 0; i < x_value.length; i++) { 
                  value[i] = Double.parseDouble(x_value[i]);
                  sum+=value[i];

                  for(int a = 0; a < weight_value.length; a++) {
                  value1[a] = Double.parseDouble(weight_value[i]);
                     sum1+=value1[a];
                  }

                result+= sum+sum1;

          }

           txtArithmetic.setText(Double.toString(result));<br/>
```

Comment: I think you are adding only sum. You should use another String variable in for loop which will create the text that will be displayed as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The way I am looking at it you're basically just adding all the numbers inputted together.

(10+20)+(20+30)+(30+40)

Is the same as

(10+20+20+30+30+40)

So that being said what you want to do first is split your values. Given a string of values, input, and an array, valArray, below I wrote some quick code that should give you a general idea of what you want to do.

```
input = input.replace(",", "-");
double sum = 0.0;
String[] arrValue = input.split(",");
for(int i = 0; i < arrValue.length; i++)
{
      sum += (Double.parseDouble(arrValue[i]);
}
return sum;
```

So basically since you're only doing addition all you need is something to separate each value. Once each value is separated you can use a split to move it into an array. Once the values are in the array you can loop through the array adding each number (parsing it to a double) and then you're left with the sum.

I hope this was what you were looking for it wasn't entirely too clear to me but this seemed more or less what you wanted.